# Has the Daily Scrum be held every day of the sprint?

Tags: scrum, daily-scrum

According the [Scrum Guide](https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-daily): The Daily Scrum is held every day of the Sprint.

Considering that the Sprint Planning, can last for up to 8 hours, has the Daily Scrum be held as well during the days of Sprint Planning, Sprint Review or Sprint Retrospective?

Comment: How long are your sprints, that your planning takes a whole day?

Comment: Sprint Planning is time-boxed to a maximum of eight hours for a one-month Sprint, I am just asking that question because the possibility of having a whole day sprint planning exists, and in that case there is no time to do the daily scrum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on when your other events are scheduled.

The purpose of the Daily Scrum is to coordinate among the team - to inspect progress toward the Sprint Goal and adapt. If you no longer have time to make progress toward the Sprint Goal, why would you need to inspect your progress and adapt your plans to achieving it?

Ultimately, I think it depends on exactly when you are holding your other events. For example, I was once using [LeSS](https://less.works/) to scale Scrum to 4 development teams working on a single product. One day was "Sprint Day" - the morning was the Sprint Review (a single event for the 4 teams) and the afternoon was the teams conducting their Sprint Retrospective and Sprint Planning. On these days, we did not hold a Daily Scrum, simply because it made sense - no team was working toward a Sprint Goal.

However, if you situation is different, you may want to hold a Daily Scrum. For example, you may have your Sprint Review in the afternoon. That may lead to several hours in the morning and a touchpoint for the team to coordinate may be valuable.

Answer (score 2):

As a Scrum Master I offer my team the option of not having a daily Scrum on the day they do sprint planning.

Some teams are happy to skip it and others prefer to stick to the routine.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended yes. 15 mins of Standup should be doable. When Sprint Planning is scheduled, the team members assemble together either way. Therefore after the Planning is over, the team may just quickly run over the priority tasks and pick a story to work on next.